# Change MTU without infrastructure change

Tags: cisco, network-core, mtu, vxlan

It's very strange issue, on openstack cluster we have `VxLAN` between network and compute node and its using `1450` MTU (1500-50) because of encap header. Because of it some of my application not working properly. I am planning to increase MTU (jumbo) `9000` on all my openstack cluster node so question is in that case do i need to increase MTU on all my physical cisco switches? We don't want to do that.

Just wanted to know increase host MTU size required network switch MTU size to?

Reference question i have posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322011/multiple-puppetmaster-behind-load-balancer/322126#322126

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't described the network very well, but if your switches are not set to use jumbo frames, any jumbo frames reaching a switch will be dropped as a giant.

Jumbo frames are not really standardized. You need to make sure that all the devices through which the jumbo frames pass can handle the maximum MTU of any frames passing through those devices.

Comment: our legacy network running on `1500` which we can't change because of production. Can i change openstack Host MTU to `1550` i believe it will solve my problem but not sure about how lagacy cisco switch will react on `1550` MTU

Comment: Cisco switches default to the standard-defined ethernet 1500 MTU (plus 18 or 22 bytes for the ethernet frame itself). Any frames larger than 1518 (1522 for frames with VLAN tags) will be dropped as giants.

Comment: Why it will drop instead of doing fragments?

Comment: Ethernet (layer-2) doesn't fragment, that is in IP (layer-3). Ethernet drops and increments the interface error counter.

Comment: agreed with you.. I can increase puppet size on neutron `l3` router so it can fragment packets.. let me think what we can do

Comment: Assuming that your frame has to pass through switches to reach your router, you will still need to increase your jumbo size on any switches that the jumbo will pass through, otherwise it won't make it to the router to be fragmented.  Also, if the traffic is between hosts on the same subnet, it won't go to the router anyway.